# How to easily insert character(s) into IntelliJ's editor

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I would like a way to easily add the character sequence `>> \`
to scripts I write in the editor, as I write this sequence a lot (it's a pipe operator in [dfply](https://github.com/kieferk/dfply)).

I have looked into doing this in two ways:

1. find a way to add a custom autocomplete for `>` (i.e., suggest `>> \` as soon as I type `>`).
2. Add a keyboard shortcut (e.g., `cmd + m`) that adds `>> \` to the editor.

However, I have not found any ways to get these potential solutions to work.

Comment: I realize this isn't the cleanest answer but you could always try a macro script such as AutoHotkey for Windows or QuicKeys for Mac.

Comment: [Live Template](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm) for #1 or record a macro and then assign custom shortcut to it for #2.